Dell Alienware M18 R2 overheating
After installing Ubuntu 24.04 on a Dell Alienware M18 R2, is overheating and the fans are not working.
I've installed a few apps trying to solve the issue but still nothing.
Would appreciate your help, ASAP.
Ps. Just bought it to start learning Cybersecurity and change Windows 11 for Ubuntu
